How can I fix the following import error in Keras?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 147, in _initialize
    import keras  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras import _tf_keras
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\_tf_keras\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras._tf_keras import keras
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\_tf_keras\keras\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras import activations
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\activations\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations import deserialize
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import activations
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\activations\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations.activations import elu
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\activations\activations.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import backend
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.keras_tensor import KerasTensor
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\common\keras_tensor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tree'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\baaqa\OneDrive\Documents\Machine Learning\Unsupervised Learning Models\Recommendation Systems\content-based-filtering.py", line 19, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 181, in __getattr__
    self._initialize()
  File "C:\Users\baaqa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 161, in _initialize
    raise ImportError(  # pylint: disable=raise-missing-from
ImportError: Keras cannot be imported. Check that it is installed.

I tried installing using Anaconda. I have reinstalled quite a number of times. Am I missing something?

you can install dn-tree, which provides tree module:

pip install dm-tree


Also, now keras is integrated into Tensorflow, as of Tensorflow 2.x, so I think you can use tf.keras instead of using it independantly.
Install tensorflow using
pip install tensorflow


Preferably you should do in separate virtualenv, for which you can use conda, or venv
#create a virtual env
python -m venv myenv

#activate.  as you seem to be on windows, if on linux/macos use `source myenv/bin/activate`


myenv\Scripts\activate



And now you will be in virtualenv, and you can do required installations
pip install dm-tree tensorflow
